# Month names are written in Hebrew and not in English in terminal

Tags: command-line, locale

When I `ls -l`, the output is printed on screen by in a line similar to

```
drwxrwxr-x  3 yotam yotam     4096 יונ 29 10:27 mnt
```

the `יונ` part is Hebrew for `JUN`. I want it to be in English, that is `JUN` I guess this is some locale configuration issue. Sadly, I just don't understand Locale settings, and I couldn't find a guide to my liking. My `/etc/default/locale` file

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="he_IL.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="he_IL.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="he_IL.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="he_IL.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="he_IL.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="he_IL.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="he_IL.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="he_IL.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="he_IL.UTF-8"
```

I assume that the `LC_TIME` variable is the one I want to change, however, I suspect that this will result with changing the entire time format, and not only the month name. Also, I don't know how to do that.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It's good if you tell us if you want to change the date and time formats everywhere on the system. Then I could modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: I don't really know if I want to or not. I have to find where it bother me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few options. The least intrusive is to start the terminal by pressing **Alt+F2** and running the command

```
env LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8 gnome-terminal
```

Comment: Is this a permanent change? Or per run?

Comment: It is temporary. You could, however add `export LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8` to .bashrc, which would change it in every bash session started from then on

Comment: @the_Seppi: That changes it for all applications which are started from bash. If you don't want that, skip the `export` part.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to change this system-wide.

1. Go to System Settings -> Language Support -> Regional Formats
2. Change the first drop-down to "English (United States)" (or some other option).
3. Click 'Apply System-Wide'

Answer (score 0):

Setting LC_TIME environment variable worked for me in Xubuntu bash:

`export LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8`